# What are real-world examples of C++ multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Besides textbook examples -- in the real world -- does it ever make sense to use multiple inheritance (where more than one of the base classes are not pure interfaces) in C++?

Comment: +1 in almost 20 years of C++ programming I have *never* been in a situation where I have *needed* to use multiple inheritence.

Comment: @Raedwald that doesn't mean that somebody shouldn't know how Multiple Inheritance in C++ works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's very common when using [Policy-based design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design), for example.

Comment: There's a textbook example there, but nothing cited from the real world.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest to point at `iostream`, which inherits from `istream` and `ostream`. `cin` and `cout` are `istream` and `ostream` respectively but `fstream` derives from `iostream`.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's ATL (Active Template Library) uses multiple inheritance as mixin classes:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Template_Library

Answer (score 2):

IMO, it's open to argument. Prior to templates, there were a fair number of cases that justified it. Basically, you could use base classes about like you can use policy classes with templates. For example, consider a template like:

```
template <typename policy1, typename policy2>
class whatever {
    policy1 p1;
    policy2 p2;
public:
    void dosomething() { if (p1.enquire()) p2.dosomething(); }
};
```

If you'd rather not use templates for some reason, you can get (some) fairly similar capabilities with multiple inheritance:

```
class whatever : policy1, policy2 {   
    void dosomething() { if (enquire()) dosomething();  }
```

};

In both cases, you're basically embedding an instance of the "policy" into your new object. Since we're using private inheritance, there's no concern with the LSP -- much like with policy-based templates, the intent isn't to create a large hierarchy that asserts anything about relationships between the members of the hierarchy -- rather, it's simply about creating the ability to create a large variety of unrelated classes on demand.

Answer (score 0):

I have used multiple inheritance in the 'real world' - in a job where I was involved in coding a mapping application.

Unfortunately, I cannot remember the exact example which I find incredibly frustrating.

However, here is an interesting article about points to consider and alternative patterns or solutions to consider using:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.2

I like the use of vehicles for the examples - particularly adding in the amphibious vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance definitely has its place and it can be very useful. As a general guideline a base class should be abstract whenever possible, which means you shouldnt be able to create an object out of it, but nothing stop you from inheriting from concrete class. It is definitely a merit too t hat you can take advantage of the inherited implementation from base class. Example on one of the answer on iostream is a good one. Another example is perhaps to say modelling a employee who is also an owner/director of a business and you will model it as

```
public class Director
{
   ................
   double CalculateDividend();
   bool ApproveBudget();
};

public class Employee
{
   ................
   double CalculateSalary();
};


public class WorkingDirector: Employee, Director
{
   ..............
};
```

Now a WorkingDirector object can do what an Employee and a Director can do, which is a perfect in realworld. We wouldnt even need to overwrite any method implementation.

In many cases implementing design patterns are also made easier with multiple inheritance support.

Comment: This is not a real word example.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a class batsman which has data members like no of runs,no. of sixes, no of fours, batting average, run-rate  etc. We have another class 'Bowler' which may have data members like no.of wickets taken, runs-per-over, average-wicket etc. For a player who is an all rounder, the class 'All-Rounder' will be derived from both the classes 'Batsman' and "Bowler'.
This can be cited as a real world example of multiple inheritance